# ASP.NET Cannot create ActiveX component on 64bit Windows server 2008 R2

Tags: asp.net, vba, iis-7.5, activexobject, windows-server-2008-x64

I am having a website in which users upload xslm (excel) files and in turn a macro is run in these files at the server. I unable to get this done; when I deploy it on IIS 7.5 (Win Server 2008 R2) an exception is generated

System.Exception: Cannot create ActiveX component

I checked windows log, it says:

The machine-default permission settings do not grant Local Activation permission for the COM Server application with CLSID 
{00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}
 and APPID 
Unavailable
 to the user IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool SID (S-1-5-82-3006700770-424185619-1745488364-794895919-4004696415) from address LocalHost (Using LRPC). This security permission can be modified using the Component Services administrative tool.

I checked steps listed on [ASP.NET Cannot create ActiveX component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1847444/asp-net-cannot-create-activex-component), however it is not useful to me as there is no component (Microsoft Excel Application) in the hierarchy:

Component Services -> Computers -> My Computer -> DCOM Config -> Microsoft Excel Application

Please help

Comment: Can anybody help on this? This was a bit urgent.. :-(

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to grant permissions to Excel from DCOM
2. Check the version(as in 32bit & 64bit) of Office on your computer.
3. On 64 bit system with 32 bit Office try this:
   start -> run -> mmc -32
   File -> Add/Remove Snap in

Component Services -> Add. Then press "OK"

Console Root>Component Services>Computers>My Computer>DCOM Config>Microsoft Excel Application (shud be present!)
...
grant the permissions and try...

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Start
Run
mmc -32
File
Add Remove Snap-in
Component Services
Add
OK
Console Root
Component Services
Computers
My Computer
DCOM Config
Microsoft Excel Application