# SSIS Package running macro on an Excel not working as part of SQL Server Agent Job

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba, ssis

I have as SSIS package which calls a macro on multiple Excel files one by one. Although this package runs correctly from BIDS as well as from SQL Server stored packages - > Run Package option. But it fails with below exception when executed as a step in a SQL Server Agent Job.

Exception:

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown
>   by the target of an invocation. --->  System.Exception: Cannot create
>   ActiveX component.      at
>   Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.CreateObject(String ProgId, String
>   ServerName)
>        at ST_4fc395700019420780960cffb1260896.vbproj.ScriptMain.Main()
>          --- End of inner exception stack trace 
>          ---     at System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeMethodFast(Object target, Object[] 
>          arguments, SignatureStruct& sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeTypeHandle typeOwner) 
>              at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder,
>               Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks)
>               at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder,
>                Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
>                at System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags bindingFlags, 
>                Binder binder, Object target, Object[] providedArgs, ParameterModifier[] modifiers,
>                 CultureInfo culture, String[] namedParams)      at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTATaskScriptingEngine.ExecuteScript()

Answer (score 0):

Might be useful to look at this [entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1847444/asp-net-cannot-create-activex-component) where giving `NETWORK SERVICE` access to the `DCOM Config -> Microsoft Excel Application` resolves the issue.

Comment: Could you please tell me why this issue is occuring only when I run SSIS package calling excel macro as an SSIS Job step?