# ASP .NET / VB .net Using Microsoft Interop Word - CreateObject("Word.Application") Crash

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ms-word, office-interop, word-interop

I'm just trying to fill a word dot file (using bookmark) with my asp net vb net webform site using Microsoft Interop Word.

It works perfectly in debug on my IIS Express, but crash on my Windows Server 2016 / IIS 10.

```
Dim oWord As Word.Application
oWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
```

Server crash with message like this :

`Cannot create ActiveX component.` (original error message : Impossible de créer le composant ActiveX.)

I was searching for a fix, but a lot of post about this error are old.

I tried to check the server registry and the key {000209FF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} is here with Microsoft Word Application as data.

On the server Microsoft Office 2016 is installed with Word.

Thanks you

EDIT 12/08/2020 : Issue was about server usage of Interop Word.
To fix this i had to use OpenXML instead.

Comment: Just read post about this issue. Seems like i need to activate something in DCOM Configuration, but i don't really know what to activate nor the way to do it.
https://forums.asp.net/post/3722378.aspx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET Cannot create ActiveX component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1847444/asp-net-cannot-create-activex-component)

Answer (score 1):

> All versions of Microsoft Office were designed, tested, and configured to run as end-user products on a client workstation. They assume an interactive desktop and user profile. They do not provide the level of reentrancy or security that is necessary to meet the needs of server-side components that are designed to run unattended.
>
> Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.

You may consider using the Open XML SDK instead if you deal with open XML documents only.  See [Welcome to the Open XML SDK 2.5 for Office](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/open-xml-sdk) for more information.

Otherwise, you may use any third-party components designed for server-side execution (for example, Aspose).

Comment: _"All current versions [...] in this environment."_ - if you quote a text from somewhere, format it as a quote and cite your sources.

Answer (score 0):

[ASP.NET Cannot create ActiveX component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1847444/asp-net-cannot-create-activex-component)

This link is actually what i'm searching for, but i don't have any Microsoft Word Application in my DCOM config.

Comment: Tried to open DCOM Conf on 32 bits mode, couldn't have Word Application neither

Answer (score 0):

In most cases (by default), your local in-process web server (express) that launches from VS runs as a x32 bit web server. Your actual web server VERY likely runs as a x64 bit server. As a result, you need to install + use a x64 bit version of word. (you want to install office x64 on the server).

As noted, this tends to be a bad idea for web server code